# Can I use regular expressions with cd command in mac terminal?

Tags: regex, bash, terminal, glob, cd

I have a directory which contains the following folders.

How do I use cd command to go to folder which contains Intelligence in its name using regular expression?

```
mac@saurav 6th Semester ->ls
[CE 655] Engineering Economics
[CT 651] Object Oriented Analysis and Design
[CT 652] Database Management System
[CT 653] Artificial Intelligence
[CT 654] Minor Project
[CT 655] Embedded System
[CT 656] Operating System
```

Comment: The shell doesn't use regular expressions for filenames, it uses wildcard (or "glob") patterns. These look very similar, but have significantly different syntax. For instance, in a glib pattern, `*` means "any string", but in a regular expression it modifies whatever's right before it, meaning "any number of that last thing".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cd *Intelligence*
```

would take you to the directory that first matches this pattern.

Like if there are directories "1 Intelligence", "abc Intelligence" and "bcd Intelligence" in your current directory, it will switch to "1 Intelligence" because it is the first match.

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this `cd *Intelligence*`.